# How can i Launch context menu from Options menu item?

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

I have 2 options menu items added using the following code.

```
onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
     menu.add("ITEM1");
     menu.add("ITEM2");
     ...    
}
```

How can set context menu for one of these menu items.
Normally for Buttons and such i would use the RegisterForContextMenu()
and build the context menu from

```
onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v,ContextMenuInfo menuinfo)
{
       menu.add("ITEM1");
       menu.add("ITEM2");
       menu.add("ITEM3");
}
```

As i am unable to find a way to get the OptionsMenu View object , how can i set registerforcontextmenu()

Answer (score 4):

when you click on some item of options menu just register some button  for context view and call show context view and unregister for context view in oncreatecontextview methood as follows:-

```
registerForContextMenu(b2);//When wanna use Options menu to open a context menu                           
openContextMenu(b2);//Call register for context menu thing 
unregisterForContextMenu(b2);//////like buttton and make it invisible or out of frame
```

Comment: Actually what i want is a LongClick operation on the OptionsMenuItem, in your suggestion even if a context menu is opened its opened on click event, not on longclick Event

Comment: then do write the code in onLongPress or some kind of method if available otherwise you cannot make long press for options menu items just make sure whatever it is

Comment: Good thought though :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems long press listener is not available for options menu item.
So i guess the only option is using SubMenu.